# pandas_profiling print depreciation warning with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pandas-profiling

Environment:

1. pandas_profiling - v2.8
2. Python - 3.7.1.
3. Shell - 3.2
4. MacOs - 10.15.6

When I make a report by running

```
import pandas_profiling as pdp

df = pd.read_csv('some.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-16')
report =pdp.ProfileReport(df)
report.to_file(output_file='my_report.html')
```

I got a depreciation warning below.

```
/Users/myname/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_profiling/visualisation/plot.py:154: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: You are modifying the state of a globally registered colormap. In future versions, you will not be able to modify a registered colormap in-place. To remove this warning, you can make a copy of the colormap first. cmap = copy.copy(mpl.cm.get_cmap("RdBu"))
  cmap.set_bad(cmap_bad)
```

As I run above program line by line, the waring occurs at the last line. What does this warning mean and does it affect the output report?

Comment: It means pandas_profiling is using a matplotlib API that has been deprecated. It doesn't affect your results right now.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll wait for an update then. Thanks for your answer.